# How can I access the groovy code for the default android gradle tasks such as test, check, lint, etc?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

On running `gradlew tasks`, I see many default gradle tasks such as

```
Android tasks
-------------
androidDependencies - Displays the Android dependencies of the project.
signingReport - Displays the signing info for each variant.
sourceSets - Prints out all the source sets defined in this project.
```

How can I see the config/groovy code for the default tasks?

Comment: You mean without browsing the Android source code?

Comment: @cricket_007 is there a way to access the groovy code for the default tasks easily from Android Studio?

Comment: I understood the question... And I'm asking you, why can't you dig through the Android source code? You aren't going to find what you want "within Android Studio" because that Groovy or Gradle isn't part of Android Studio